# Regex to match basic media query

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling to get my regular expression to match the following string:

```
(max-width: 320px) 280px
```

I would like my regex to split the string into two parts like so:

```
console.log(parts[0]) // (max-width: 320px)
console.log(parts[1]) // 280px
```

This is what I currently have:

```
(\(.+\))\s?(0-9a-z)+
```

I haven't written a regular expression in a while so I am a little rusty but for some reason, I cannot get it to match the final part i.e. `280px`.

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

### Additional Information

I do not need anything complex, the purpose of this regex is to match media queries used in the `sizes` attribute of the an `img` element.

As far as I can see, it simply needs to do the following:

1. Match anything within the brackets (including the brackets)
2. Match an optional space
3. Match the ending alphanumeric value (can be px/em/vw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you expression is just fine, maybe we'd just add a char class to it:

```
(\(.+\))\s*([0-9a-z]+)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/8dX2kS/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.